# how to use proxy in http-kit

Tags: clojure, http-kit

I am using http-client in clojure with proxy. And I want to try http-kit, however I don't find a way to use proxy. I have a list of proxies stored in database, and then randomly pick up a proxy and use it in http client. Look like there is no api/parameter in http-kit to use a proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an open issue for proxy support in http-kit, it doesn't support it yet. https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/issues/75